# How to translate assembly to C with stack implemented on heap?

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering, heap-memory, stack-memory

I know there are some posts talking about translate assembly to C,
but basically they all aims at how to get a ***Human Readable*** C source code.

So what I want to achieve is the translation process with stack implemented on heap.

I don't need to make the code easy to read, only translate into a legal c source code 
or even **pseudo code** (if directly translate into c source code is too hard),

but in this relatively easily task(not easy at all), I want to implement the stack on heap, just like ML and Scheme compiler have done..

Could anyone give me some guide and instructions on this stuff?

The experiment environment should be on x86, and assembly is generated from

```
gcc -S source
```

suppose we have the original c source code in this task, could it help?

Comment: Depending on where/when/how the assembly language code was generated, it may not be possible if it doesn't map onto C language semantics.

Comment: Hi, Eric, I update my questions..If I have the original C source code, could it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming x86/x64 here...

The stack pointer is tracked by ESP (32bit) or RSP (64bit) registers.
You can insert a `mov ESP, ADDRESS` instruction into the ASM and change the stack to your preferred location. You'll need to store ESP/RSP on the new stack first because you need it for later.

Immediately after setting ESP/RSP call `main()` (or any other C function for that matter) in the C program.

After function returns, restore ESP/RSP to it's original value.

Comment: Hi, egur, thank you a lot for your helpful answer! But I am still confused with some details..As for the 32 bit environments, do I have to change ss register..? cause basically I think only by combine ss:sp, you can find the exact top of stack..

Comment: And also, if I put my stack on the heap memory area, how can I guarantee that this memory area would not be overlapped by "real" heap memory manipulate functions like HeapAlloc/HeapFree in the future?

Comment: @computereasy - SS isn't used anymore (32/64 bit), just ESP/RSP. Since you allocate the stack, you control what happens with this memory. The stack allocated by the OS is a little more sophisticated, it doesn't allocate all the stack size, instead it allocates a small portion and ending the allocation with a guard page, when the guard page is accessed, it will access more space. If you're overriding the stack allocation, make sure you allocate plenty of ram.

Comment: @computereasy - stack manipulation is pretty advanced stuff, you should know all the mechanism involved before doing this.

Comment: Basically, I only know some high level idea in this area, and it seems that I need to make my hand dirty...Thank you egur!